# Integrate fabric.js in Spree

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In an attempt to use fabric.js with Spree, I came accross the Javascript error that the `require` instruction is undefined in the file `build.js` (top line). I could use the gem requirejs-rails to solve this problem, but it represents quite a change to Spree. Therefore, I would like to know if anybody came accross this problem and could provide a nifty solution?

Answer (score 0):

Two comments on this issue:

1) `build.js` was referenced because I installed `fabric.js` through `bower` while being in a directory under `@app/assets/javascript`. So the whole library was taken into the asset pipeline. I solved the problem by moving the bower components and copying over to the asset directory only the file(s) I really need. As a side note, unlike gems, bower libraries are installed in the current directory unless specified otherwise.

2) the fabric.js documentation recommends the installation via `bower`, which requires `node.js`. I then recommend to replace `therubyracer` by `node.js`: this suppresses the need for a second interpreter.